# Warning when streaming with vlc and x264 at a slow framerate

Tags: libvlc, x264, libx264

I am using libvlc and libx264 to stream images from a C++ program. It provides libvlc uncompressed images using the get and release callback. Everything seems to work ok at higher framerate (over 12 fps) but when I try slower framerates (from 1 to 10), I got the following warnings :

```
[030d5c6c] mux_ts mux debug: adjusting rate at 0/500000 (3/0)
[030d5c6c] main mux warning: late buffer for mux input (2127998)
[030d5c6c] mux_ts mux debug: adjusting rate at 0/500000 (3/0)
```

Over 4 fps, I am able to get the stream (for instance with vlc GUI) but under 4 fps, I got nothing, or sometimes a freeze image. The libvlc arguments are the following :

```
--imem-get=15543672 --imem-release=15538482 --imem-data=0 --imem-codec=RV24 --imem-cookie=aCookie --imem-cat=2 --imem-height=960 --imem-width=1280 --verbose=2 --imem-id=1 --imem-group=1 --imem-fps=2.000000 -vvv --play-and-exit --no-audio --sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264, fps=2.000000, vb=200k,venc=x264{preset=ultrafast}}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=0.0.0.0:8091/video}
```

Any hints would be appreciated.